# How do I make my homepage go fade away and reveal a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, multiplayer

I'm making a .io game in HTML CSS and JavaScript and I'm trying to have it so that when the user either clicks on the play button or presses enter the homepage fades away and it shows a canvas (the game). I believe that I have to use event listeners and a CSS animation but how do I make it fade away and not have anything on the screen but the canvas?

Note: I'm using a node.js server for this project.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>rainboz.io</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='client/styles/main.css' type="text/css">
        <base href="/">
        <script src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js'></script>
        <script src='rainboz/app.js'></script>
            var socket = io();

            var random = Math.random();

            var happy = function() {
            socket.emit('happy', {
                reason:'its my birthday' + random
            });
        }
            socket.on('serverMsg', function(data) {
                console.log(data.msg);
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--title-->

        <!--changelog-->
        <h2 id='changeot'>Changelog</h2>
        <h2 id="changein">Changelog</h2>

        <!--last upadated-->
        <h2 id='lastupot'>Last Updated: June 22, 2020</h2>
        <h2 id="lastupin">Last Updated: June 22, 2020</h2>
        
        <!--upadates-->
        <p id='toppot'>
            - I just created this changelog,<br/>
            this is where chages will go whenever I make them but <br/>
            I dont have any yet.

        </p>
        <p id='toppin'>
            - I just created this changelog,<br/>
            this is where chages will go whenever I make them but <br/>
            I dont have any yet.

        </p>

        <!--updates 2-->

        <p id='midpot'>
            - I barely even know how to code at all,<br/>
            so I'm kinda just winging it for now <br/>
            I'll just look up how to do stuff as I go.

        </p>

        <p id='midpin'>
            - I barely even know how to code at all,<br/>
            so I'm kinda just winging it for now <br/>
            I'll just look up how to do stuff as I go.
        </p>

        <h2 id="versionnumot">Version Number: 01.03.02</h2> 
        <h2 id='versionnumin'>Version Number: 01.03.02</h2>

        <h2 id='cinfoot'>Contact | About</h2>
        <h2 id='cinfoin'>Contact | About</h2>

        <!--nickname and play button-->

        <div class='ctr'>
          <h1 id='outer'>rainboz.io</h1>
          <h1 id='inner'>rainboz.io</h1>
        </div>
        
        
        <div>
          <form align="center">
            <label id='spawnif'>this is the story of...</label>
            <label id='spawnifin'>this is the story of...</label>
            <input type='text' spellcheck='false' maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
            <button id='playbtnot'>Play</button>
            <button id='playbtnin'>Play</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <form>
            <button id='rbtn'></button>
            <button id='dbtn'></button>
            <button id='ibtn'></button>
            <button id='tbtn'></button>
        </form>

            <button id='mgbtnot'>More Games</button>
            <button id='mgbtnin'>More Games</button>

            <button onclick='happy()'>Happy</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(trianglebg.png);
    background-size: 475px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    overflow: hidden;
}



@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconbold';
    src: url(Cocon-Bold-Font.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconregular';
    src: url(cocon-regular.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconlight';
    src: url(cocon-light.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#inner {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 40, 40, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 121, 4, 1) 27%, rgba(252, 241, 73, 1) 40%, rgba(82, 252, 73, 1) 50%, rgba(73, 197, 252, 1) 60%, rgba(106, 53, 255, 1) 73%, rgba(150, 0, 214, 1) 85%);
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: anim 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 0 9px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 8%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  caret-color: grey;
  animation-name: float-up-3;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#spawnif {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
  animation-name: float-up-2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#spawnifin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
      animation-name: float-up-2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#playbtnin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
      animation-name: float-up-1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#playbtnot {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(180, 179, 255);
  border-color: rgb(110, 107, 255);
  background-size: 500px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
    animation-name: float-up-1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#playbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(161, 171, 255);
  border-color: rgb(103, 101, 255);
}

.ctr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: float-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes float-in {
  from {
    top: -50%;
  }
  to {
    top: 15%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-1 {
  from {
    top: 150%;
  }
  to {
    top: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-2 {
  from {
    top: 140%;
  }
  to {
    top: 36%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-3 {
  from {
    top: 150%;
  }
  to {
    top: 40%;
  }
}

  #changeot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 7%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 33px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

  #changein {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 7%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 33px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #lastupin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #lastupot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }
  
  #toppin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 13%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #toppot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 13%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }

  #midpin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #midpot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 130px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }
  
  #versionnumin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 635px;
    left: 11.25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #versionnumot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 635px;
    left: 11.25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

    #rbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(253, 135, 106);
    border-color: rgb(255, 31, 2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #dbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1210px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(189, 204, 255);
    border-color: rgb(109, 112, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #ibtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1270px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(165, 117, 255);
    border-color: rgb(120, 2, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  
  #tbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1330px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(148, 207, 255);
    border-color: rgb(0, 110, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #cinfoin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 12px;
    right: -6%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #cinfoot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 12px;
    right: -6%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

  #mgbtnot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 1095px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(159, 255, 151);
    border-color: rgb(61, 167, 57);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }

  #mgbtnin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 1095px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }
```

My JavaScript

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
    
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client/'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connection');

    socket.on('happy', function(data) {
        console.log('happy because ' + data.reason);
    });

    socket.emit('serverMsg', {
        msg: 'hello',
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your content in a container `<div>` and when user clicks on button set `opacity: 0;` for the container `<div>`

```js
  function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById('container').style.opacity = "0";
                setTimeout(func2, 650) // after faded out 

            }
  
  function func2() {
            document.getElementById('canvas-container').style.display = "block";

        }
```

```css
  #container {
                transition: 0.6s;
                width: 100vw;
            }

            #canvas-container {
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"> <!-- Div that contains content-->
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <p>Some text...</p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
        </div>
        <div id="canvas-container"> <!-- Canvas container outside of container div -->
            <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="00"></canvas> 
            <p>If you see me that means this works!</p>
        </div>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But when I click the button it fades out but the canvas doesn't show up I tried changing the size from width="100" height="00" to width="100" height="100" but nothing showed up still, I also removed the display: none line and then I gave it a border but I still can't see a canvas.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out how to fix it, thank you so much!